# Get the CPU usage

Tags: xamarin.ios, cpu

Is this possible with Xamarin.IOS / monotouch to access the CPU usage stats?

I've searched for an API similar to what Android SDK makes accessible [/proc/stat] but found nothing, so I cannot integrate any line of code to monitor the CPU.

(I've gave a look at XCode Instruments but they are really resource consuming on my machine and slow down my application at such a point that I can't even interact with it. I have one line of code to monitor the global memory usage and would appreciate to only add a second line of code to monitor the CPU, instead of launching something throttled at 0.1 nanosecond that dumps 4GB of stock per second. I'm kidding a bit, but that summarizes my point.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Apple does not provide any public APIs for this data.

Comment: Sad, I would have appreciated submitting optimized applications.